# Angular 4 : giving concatenated values instead of adding the values

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in an angular 4 application ,In this I am trying to add 1 with the parameter value of a method .

Ex: if the method receives 1 as the parameter value I want to add parameter value + 1 inside the method .but it returns 11 instead of 2.

```
addCount(mCount){
   mCount += 1;
   console.log(mCount);
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: of course `mCount` is a string then. `mCount = parseInt(mCount) + 1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be having your value as a string, just convert it into a number before adding. Use `+` operator to convert it into a number.

```
addCount(mCount){
   mCount = +mCount + 1;
   console.log(mCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy @Prachi

Answer (score 2):

use ParseInt to convert to a number, otherwise it will be considered as a string and concatenated,

```
mCount = parseInt(mCount) + 1
```